# how to detect when a thread has completed execution in blackberry?

Tags: multithreading, blackberry

How can I detect when the below code/thread has completed execution in Blackberry:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {              
            EventInjector.KeyEvent inject = new EventInjector.KeyEvent  
                    (EventInjector.KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN,Characters.ENTER, 0);
                      inject.post();
                      inject.post();
        }
    });
```

Can I get a notification when this thread has executed so that I can start another thread? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can put a new thread inside your code  :-
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
{
    new Thread()
    {
           run()
           {
              // ..put the code you want to excute
           }
    }.start();
}
 }

Answer (score 0):

You need a synchronized block, [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_wait_notify.shtml) is a short description of how it works.

The "sleeping" thread must lock an object, and call wait() on it.
The other thread locks the same object, and sends a notify() or notifyAll() to wake up the first one.

If you start the thread explicitly (not in this case), you can simply call join() on it, and synchronously wait for it to finish.

**- Edit: using join() on a thread**

Assuming you already have a runnable object:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
myThread.start();
doOtherStuff();
myThread.join();
```

But if something goes wrong, you are stuck on the join() call, because BlackBerry has no timeout for this call.

Comment: I think that join() method would suit me but how can I accomplish that with my piece of code? I have 3 threads like this which I want to join. I need to confirm the run order of threads on all runs.

Comment: while(total>0){  Thread t1=new Thrd1();
    t1.start();
    try { t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    Thread t2=new Thrd2();
    t2.start();
    try { t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {   e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    Thread t3=new Thrd3();    
    t3.start();
    try { t3.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {     
     e.printStackTrace();
    }        
    Thread t4=new Thrd4();
    t4.start();
    try { t4.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {     
     e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    --total;

Comment: @nikitasharma It would be better to put the code that you tried, etc in the original question. Also, when you say "But doesnt work", what happens exactly?

Comment: You can use join() on the thread if you started it explicitly (that is: not on a Runnable that the UI thread executes for you).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the join() method is used to determine when a thread has finished. Calling join() typically blocks, so use it with care.

[Here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) is a reference.